# "Invalid field override named 'id' for class ..." error while generating entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

How to create mapping.yaml with inheritance that is suitable for 'generate:entities' command? I tried like this:

```
Acme\EdgarMainBundle\Entity\Address:
  type: entity
  table: address
  repositoryClass: AddressRepository
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      autoincrement: true
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  inheritanceType: SINGLE_TABLE
  discriminatorColumn:
    name: discr
    type: string
    length: 255
  discriminatorMap:
    customeraddress: Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Customeraddress
    corporationaddress: Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Corporationaddress
  fields:
    ...

Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Customeraddress:
  type: entity
  repositoryClass: CustomeraddressRepository
  fields:
    ...

Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Corporationaddress:
  type: entity
  repositoryClass: CorporationaddressRepository
  fields:
    ...
```

but I have an error:

```
Entity class 'Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Customeraddress' used in the discriminator map of class 'Acme\EdgarMainBundle\Entity\Address' does not exist.
```

Yes, I can create it by myself, but is there way to do it with

```
doctrine:generate:entities MyBundle
```

command?

Comment: Did you solve the issue? if the answer helps you, please you mark it as accepter answer, otherwise please share your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
doctrine:generate:entities MyBundle
```

should be changed to

```
doctrine:generate:entities AcmeMyBundle
```

or

```
doctrine:generate:entities Acme/MyBundle
```

documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#generating-getters-and-setters